# BlueMix SSO Cloud Directory group mapping security-role not working

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I have a local Liberty Profile instance running that is connected to the BlueMix SSO service.  Authentication seems to be working but I am not getting the groups populated in my Subject.

In my basicRegistry I get this using Form Authc:

```
com.ibm.ws.security.credentials.wscred.WSCredentialImpl com.ibm.ws.security.credentials.wscred.WSCredentialImpl@3fb28fe1,realmName=BasicRealm,securityName=user1,realmSecurityName=BasicRealm/user1,uniqueSecurityName=user1,primaryGroupId=group:BasicRealm/admin,accessId=user:BasicRealm/user1,groupIds=[group:BasicRealm/admin]
```

When I authenticate against the BlueMix SSO Cloud Directory authc I get this:

```
com.ibm.ws.security.credentials.wscred.WSCredentialImpl com.ibm.ws.security.credentials.wscred.WSCredentialImpl@5b91df41,realmName=www.ibm.com,securityName=<ssoservice-name>.iam.ibmcloud.com/www.ibm.com/user1,realmSecurityName=www.ibm.com/<ssoservice-name>.iam.ibmcloud.com/www.ibm.com/user1,uniqueSecurityName=<ssoservice-name>.iam.ibmcloud.com/www.ibm.com/user1,primaryGroupId=null,accessId=user:www.ibm.com/<ssoservice-name>.iam.ibmcloud.com/www.ibm.com/user1,groupIds=[]
```

But I can see that it is getting to the Cloud Directory as I can see the groups coming back in the ID Token Details:
Claims

```
{"ext":"{\"tenantId\":\"<ssoservice-name>.iam.ibmcloud.com\",\"groups\":[\"allUsers\",\"admin\"],
```

I have tried few different mappings to get these groups out but I haven't been able to figure it out and I've run out of dW and google searches:

```
<security-role name="admin"><group name="admin" access-id="group:www.ibm.com/admin"></group></security-role>
```

Is it possible to get the correct configuration to properly populate the groups for my Subject declaratively?  I am hoping to actually use more that just ALL_AUTH_USERS in my authorization scheme.

```
<security-role name="authcUsers"><special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS"></special-subject></security-role>
```

UPDATE::02JUL16 - So it seems to be able to pick up specific users, user1 below was mapped to admin role, but the last SSO group mapping still doesn't work.

```
<security-role name="admin">
            <user name="user1" access-id="user:www.ibm.com/<sso-service>.iam.ibmcloud.com/www.ibm.com/user1"/>
            <group name="admin" access-id="group:BasicRealm/admin"/>
            <group name="admin" access-id="group:www.ibm.com/<sso-service>.iam.ibmcloud.com/www.ibm.com/admin"/>
```

Regards,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group role is not supported in current Bluemix SSO service. Your observation on user role was correct. You can do user role authorization. This link tells the format you would need to specify for the user to permit the access -> https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_config_authorization-roles.html

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It seems that breaks most benefits of JAAS and/or JEE security like @RolesAllowed("authcUsers").  Sure would be nice to know if this is a temporary implementation gap or the long term direction for Bluemix SSO as mapping each user doesn't work for anything other than ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS.  I guess my plan is to use a @Interceptors(SecurityInterceptor.class) that will check for normal JAAS Subject group membership and if not found check the ID Token Claims for group membership listed there or reject.  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Yes, this is a current limitation.